# How to group by array object and create array with value key javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, adonis.js

How to group by array object from values to create new array object of values

**Input**

```
var promotions = [
    {
        "promotionID": 2,
        "id": 1,
        "qty": 1,
        "productID": 1,
        "product": "Nu Milk Tea 330ml",
        "operator": null
    }, {
        "promotionID": 2,
        "id": 2,
        "qty": 2,
        "productID": 2,
        "product": "Product testing 2",
        "operator": 1
    }, {
        "promotionID": 2,
        "id": 3,
        "qty": 3,
        "productID": 3,
        "product": "Golda Coffee Dolce Latte 200ml",
        "operator": 2
    }, {
        "promotionID": 3,
        "id": 4,
        "qty": 8,
        "productID": 54,
        "product": "Masker Skrineer 3ply Motif 5pcs",
        "operator": null
    }, {
        "promotionID": 3,
        "id": 5,
        "qty": 5,
        "productID": 53,
        "product": "Masker Skrineer 1ply Grey 5pcs",
        "operator": 2
    }, {
        "promotionID": 3,
        "id": 6,
        "qty": 5,
        "productID": 52,
        "product": "Oronamin C Drink 120ml",
        "operator": 1
    }]
```

I want to make a new array of car objects that's grouped by `promotionID`

**Expected Output**

```
[
    {
        "promotionID": 2,
        "data" : [
            {
                "promotionID": 2,
                "id": 1,
                "qty": 1,
                "productID": 1,
                "product": "Nu Milk Tea 330ml",
                "operator": null
            }, {
                "promotionID": 2,
                "id": 2,
                "qty": 2,
                "productID": 2,
                "product": "Product testing 2",
                "operator": 1
            }, {
                "promotionID": 2,
                "id": 3,
                "qty": 3,
                "productID": 3,
                "product": "Golda Coffee Dolce Latte 200ml",
                "operator": 2
            } 
        ]
    },
    {
        "promotionID": 3,
        "data" : [
            {
                "promotionID": 3,
                "id": 4,
                "qty": 8,
                "productID": 54,
                "product": "Masker Skrineer 3ply Motif 5pcs",
                "operator": null
            }, {
                "promotionID": 3,
                "id": 5,
                "qty": 5,
                "productID": 53,
                "product": "Masker Skrineer 1ply Grey 5pcs",
                "operator": 2
            }, {
                "promotionID": 3,
                "id": 6,
                "qty": 5,
                "productID": 52,
                "product": "Oronamin C Drink 120ml",
                "operator": 1
            }
        ]
    }
 
]
```

Comment: I'd use a for loop, or maybe even array reduce method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `reduce` to group promotion by promotionId and then map through the entries to get the final result

```js
var promotions = [
  {
    promotionID: 2,
    id: 1,
    qty: 1,
    productID: 1,
    product: 'Nu Milk Tea 330ml',
    operator: null
  },
  {
    promotionID: 2,
    id: 2,
    qty: 2,
    productID: 2,
    product: 'Product testing 2',
    operator: 1
  },
  {
    promotionID: 2,
    id: 3,
    qty: 3,
    productID: 3,
    product: 'Golda Coffee Dolce Latte 200ml',
    operator: 2
  },
  {
    promotionID: 3,
    id: 4,
    qty: 8,
    productID: 54,
    product: 'Masker Skrineer 3ply Motif 5pcs',
    operator: null
  },
  {
    promotionID: 3,
    id: 5,
    qty: 5,
    productID: 53,
    product: 'Masker Skrineer 1ply Grey 5pcs',
    operator: 2
  },
  {
    promotionID: 3,
    id: 6,
    qty: 5,
    productID: 52,
    product: 'Oronamin C Drink 120ml',
    operator: 1
  }
]

const res = Array.from(
  promotions
    .reduce((acc, promotion) => {
      acc.set(
        promotion.promotionID,
        (acc.get(promotion.promotionID) || []).concat(promotion)
      )
      return acc
    }, new Map)
    .entries(),
  ([promotionId, data]) => ({ promotionId, data })
)

console.log(res)
```

Comment: since Array.from takes a second argument, a map function, you could replace `).map(([promotionId, data]) => ({ promotionId, data }))` with `,(([promotionId, data]) => ({ promotionId, data })))` (that's how I was writing it when your answer popped up)

Comment: @JaromandaX cool, updated my answer. Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: you can also just do `new Map` instead of `new Map()` (I like to minimize code as much as possible :p

Comment: @JaromandaX haha no worries I like that. But wondering why without parenthesis it still works

Comment: see [new operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) ... the syntax is `new constructor[([arguments])]` ... anything in `[]` is optional ... javascript was written like this - I guess saving two characters whenever possible was important in the days of 36k dialup :p

Comment: @JaromandaX oh, that critical `[]`, cool bananas, a helpful TIL for me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer

```js
var promotions = [
  {
    promotionID: 2,
    id: 1,
    qty: 1,
    productID: 1,
    product: "Nu Milk Tea 330ml",
    operator: null,
  },
  {
    promotionID: 2,
    id: 2,
    qty: 2,
    productID: 2,
    product: "Product testing 2",
    operator: 1,
  },
  {
    promotionID: 2,
    id: 3,
    qty: 3,
    productID: 3,
    product: "Golda Coffee Dolce Latte 200ml",
    operator: 2,
  },
  {
    promotionID: 3,
    id: 4,
    qty: 8,
    productID: 54,
    product: "Masker Skrineer 3ply Motif 5pcs",
    operator: null,
  },
  {
    promotionID: 3,
    id: 5,
    qty: 5,
    productID: 53,
    product: "Masker Skrineer 1ply Grey 5pcs",
    operator: 2,
  },
  {
    promotionID: 3,
    id: 6,
    qty: 5,
    productID: 52,
    product: "Oronamin C Drink 120ml",
    operator: 1,
  },
];

const objectPromotion = {};

for (index in promotions) {
  const dataPromotion = objectPromotion[promotions[index].promotionID];
  console.log("dataPromotion", dataPromotion)
  if (dataPromotion) {
    dataPromotion.push(promotions[index]);
  } else {
    objectPromotion[promotions[index].promotionID] = [promotions[index]];
  }
}

const result = Object.keys(objectPromotion).map((item) => {
  return {
    promotionID: item,
    data: objectPromotion[item],
  };
});

console.log("result", result)
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use lodash like this.

```
const _ = require('lodash');
let filteredPromotions=_.groupBy(promotions,'promotionID');
```

output:

```
{
  '2': [
    {
      promotionID: 2,
      id: 1,
      qty: 1,
      productID: 1,
      product: 'Nu Milk Tea 330ml',
      operator: null
    },
    {
      promotionID: 2,
      id: 2,
      qty: 2,
      productID: 2,
      product: 'Product testing 2',
      operator: 1
    },
    {
      promotionID: 2,
      id: 3,
      qty: 3,
      productID: 3,
      product: 'Golda Coffee Dolce Latte 200ml',
      operator: 2
    }
  ],
  '3': [
    {
      promotionID: 3,
      id: 4,
      qty: 8,
      productID: 54,
      product: 'Masker Skrineer 3ply Motif 5pcs',
      operator: null
    },
    {
      promotionID: 3,
      id: 5,
      qty: 5,
      productID: 53,
      product: 'Masker Skrineer 1ply Grey 5pcs',
      operator: 2
    },
    {
      promotionID: 3,
      id: 6,
      qty: 5,
      productID: 52,
      product: 'Oronamin C Drink 120ml',
      operator: 1
    }
  ]
}
```

to get exact output add those lines:

```
    filteredPropomotions = Object.keys(filteredPropomotions).map((key, index)=> {return{promotionID:key,data:filteredPropomotions[key]}}
);
```

output:

```
[
    {
        "promotionID": 2,
        "data" : [
            {
                "promotionID": 2,
                "id": 1,
                "qty": 1,
                "productID": 1,
                "product": "Nu Milk Tea 330ml",
                "operator": null
            }, {
                "promotionID": 2,
                "id": 2,
                "qty": 2,
                "productID": 2,
                "product": "Product testing 2",
                "operator": 1
            }, {
                "promotionID": 2,
                "id": 3,
                "qty": 3,
                "productID": 3,
                "product": "Golda Coffee Dolce Latte 200ml",
                "operator": 2
            } 
        ]
    },
    {
        "promotionID": 3,
        "data" : [
            {
                "promotionID": 3,
                "id": 4,
                "qty": 8,
                "productID": 54,
                "product": "Masker Skrineer 3ply Motif 5pcs",
                "operator": null
            }, {
                "promotionID": 3,
                "id": 5,
                "qty": 5,
                "productID": 53,
                "product": "Masker Skrineer 1ply Grey 5pcs",
                "operator": 2
            }, {
                "promotionID": 3,
                "id": 6,
                "qty": 5,
                "productID": 52,
                "product": "Oronamin C Drink 120ml",
                "operator": 1
            }
        ]
    }
 
]
```